# Relationship between instance of classes and its companion object

Tags: scala, object

I have the following class and companion object:

```
class TestMatch(val i: Int)

object TestMatch{
  def apply(i: Int) = new TestMatch(i)
  def unapply(tm : TestMatch): Option[Int] = Some(tm.i)
}
```

Now consider the following simple program:

```
println("isAssignableFrom: " + classOf[TestMatch].isAssignableFrom((tm.getClass)))
println("equality: " + classOf[TestMatch].equals((tm.getClass)))
println("instanceOf:" + TestMatch.isInstanceOf[TestMatch])
```

it prints:

```
isAssignableFrom: true
equality: true
instanceOf:false
```

How is it possible? Have not come across with this in Java yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not referring to the same `TestMatch` concept in each example.

- `classOf[TestMatch]` and `instanceOf[TestMatch]` refer to `TestMatch` as a type. Singletons do not define a type.
- `TestMatch.something()` is a call to a method on the singleton object `TestMatch`

Now what can be a bit confusing is the following:

```
object Singleton
println(Singleton.isInstanceOf[Singleton]) // prints true
```

I'm guessing Scala gives the priority to the class when a singleton is a companion-object.

**Edit:**

As Alexey Romanov pointed out, `scala.Singleton` is actually defined in the Scala SDK which every singleton object extends... Let's start again with a different name:

```
object MySingleton
println(MySingleton.isInstanceOf[MySingleton])
```

This does not compile, because a singleton does not define a type. There's a way to make it compile.

```
println(MySingleton.isInstanceOf[MySingleton.type]) // true
```

That's how you can demonstrate that you were not referring to the same thing. Final example, let's try

```
class MyClassWithCompanion
object MyClassWithCompanion

val x = new MyClassWithCompanion

println(MyClassWithCompanion.isInstanceOf[MyClassWithCompanion])      // false
println(MyClassWithCompanion.isInstanceOf[MyClassWithCompanion.type]) // true
println(MyClassWithCompanion.isInstanceOf[x.type]                     // false
```

That's pretty subtle, but here's what it means:

- `.type` is an operator that is applied to an instance and returns its type
- `x.type` can only be defined if `x` is an instance of something, so `MyClass.type` would not compile unless this class has a companion object. Therefore, `MyClassWithCompanion.type` necessarily refers to the companion object (which is an instance) and not to the class itself
- the type of a companion and the type of the class itself are different. You could not substitute an instance of `X` with the singleton `X`, which makes sense because they are of a different nature.

Comment: @stella yeah but it's not so simple, I'm still researching to see if this behaviour is specified somewhere

Comment: The second `Singleton` is `scala.Singleton` which every `object` extends.

Comment: Your example is excellent, but demonstates really strange behavior (to me, at least). Don't you know why did they do so?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I added a few things in my answer, you seem to be more of a Scala shaman than I am so I would appreciate if you could suggest anything to improve, or add your own answer if needed. Cheers :)

Comment: @Dici I am not sure what you last sentence means. Do you mean that `class A; object A; println(A.isInstanceOf[A.type])` prints `false`?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov that's what I meant, but after double-checking it's wrong. I got it wrong during my quick test because of a bad copy-paste ! Thank you, I'll edit my answer

Comment: @stella added a few things in my answer. It's only based on my own understanding of these snippets, it would also be good to see how this is rigourously specified by the language

Comment: `.type` is the _singleton_ type (i.e. the type which has only `x` as a value). Note that `(new MyClassWithCompanion).isInstanceOf[x.type]` is also false.

Comment: Yup, I got it. Did my answer seem to imply something else ?